# How to get information to display as columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following dataset:

```
 ID | Place | Type | Count
 1  | Home  | A    | 12
 2  | Home  | B    | 15
 3  | Home  | C    | 16
 4  | Work  | A    | 35
 5  | Work  | B    | 23
 6  | Work  | C    | 55
```

I want to end up with:

```
 ID | Place | A  | B  | C
 1  | Home  | 12 | 15 | 16
 3  | Work  | 35 | 23 | 55
```

What sql do I need to get this result?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: This is very tedious thing to understand this question.. How ID "3" is expected output for your second record???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned any RDBMS, this query will work on many RDBMS.

```
SELECT  MIN(ID) ID,
        Place,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'A' THEN count END) A,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'B' THEN count END) B,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'C' THEN count END) C
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY Place
```

Here's a dynamic version if you have unknown number of `Type`.

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN Type = ''',
               Type,
               ''' THEN Count ELSE NULL END) AS ',
               CONCAT('`', Type, '`')
               )) INTO @sql
FROM TableName;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT MIN(ID) ID,s.Place, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM TableName s
                   GROUP BY s.Place');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both statements*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81454/2)
- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
- [MySQL Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

OUTPUT from both statement

```
+----+-------+----+----+----+
| ID | PLACE | A  | B  | C  |
+----+-------+----+----+----+
|  1 | Home  | 12 | 15 | 16 |
|  4 | Work  | 35 | 23 | 55 |
+----+-------+----+----+----+
```

**UPDATE 1**

Note: the `GROUP_CONCAT` result length is limited to the value of the [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) system variable, which has a default value of 1024. So, if you have large number of columns, then this value can be set higher before using `GROUP_CONCAT` function, for example:

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 5000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this static query (if you have known and limited numbers of Type):

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, Place
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'A' THEN Count ELSE 0 END) AS A
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'B' THEN Count ELSE 0 END) AS B
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'C' THEN Count ELSE 0 END) AS C
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Place
```

Or you can also use this dynamic query (if you do not know the number of Type) (for MySQL):

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when `Type` = ''',
      `Type`,
      ''' then Count END) AS `',
      `Type`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM MyTable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, Place, ', @sql, '
                  FROM MyTable 
                   GROUP BY Place 
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b30a/4)

Result:

```
╔════╦═══════╦════╦════╦════╗
║ ID ║ PLACE ║ A  ║ B  ║ C  ║
╠════╬═══════╬════╬════╬════╣
║  1 ║ Home  ║ 12 ║ 15 ║ 16 ║
║  4 ║ Work  ║ 35 ║ 23 ║ 55 ║
╚════╩═══════╩════╩════╩════╝
```